# App crash when passint new float value

Tags: android, android-custom-view

- What causes app crash?

I have an app based on BluetoothChat sample. I created new package and there i hold my view classes like speedometer. I want to get a value from BluetoothChat.java and set it in Speedometer.java
Therefore there is onSpeedChangeListener interface

[image]

Added this in BluetoothChat:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(readMessage.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));               
                speedValue = (float)i;                
                final Speedometer speedometer = (Speedometer) findViewById(R.id.Speedometer);
                speedometer.onSpeedChanged(speedValue);
```

SpeedChangeListener:

```
package lt.vejoprojektai.View;

public interface SpeedChangeListener {

    public void onSpeedChanged(float newSpeedValue);

}
```

Speedometer.java

```
@Override
    public void onSpeedChanged(float newSpeedValue) {
        this.setCurrentSpeed(newSpeedValue);
        this.invalidate();
    }
```

If i comment lines in BluetoothChat that try to pass value app works.

LogCat:

```
06-14 14:00:57.100: W/dalvikvm(24290): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415b5b90)
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290): Process: com.example.android.BluetoothChat, PID: 24290
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290):    at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat$2.handleMessage(BluetoothChat.java:299)
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811)
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627)
06-14 14:00:57.110: E/AndroidRuntime(24290):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit
[image]

Edit2

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final int mUIFlag = 
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

        // Set up the window layout
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

And then with a button in menu i open new view `setContentView(R.layout.cluster);` but the menu is not hidden...

Comment: Debug and check there is a problem at line num 299 in `BluetoothChat.java` some thing went null

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to copy code with line number so i added Print Screen. So i believe there is something with 295,296 lines and when it try to break it goes to null, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Error **NullPointerException** i think its by resource of speedometer not found,

make sure if speedometer is in the same layout and if not then you should inflate the view layout from where it can get.

i dont think any parsing of float error in this.
Good luck

Comment: That should make sense :) Because my main layout is basic BluetoothChat layout. I didn't know how to open my layout and leave all bluetooth service working. Anyway, i made a button in menu, when pressed to open new intent. Probably i should add all bluetoothChat code?

Comment: if i am thinking right then one another way to open your another layout without changing activity is to **setContentView(R.layout.chatLayout);** again when you need.

Comment: Basically i need one layout. I open my layout in strange way i think :D this is in public void onCreate
`this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Cluster.class);
     myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(myIntent);`

Comment: Obviusly!! you are opening a new activity with intent that is not good. You hvae to just write again **setContentView(R.layout.chatLayout);** and you get your another view. its not a big prob

Comment: So if i make `Intent intent = new intent...` i stop BluetoothChat activity? i made `setContentView(R.layout.cluster);` and it works, no app crash, but now its not full screen. When i made with Intent the return, home menu was hiden. Have any ideas? Basically you answered my question, but if you have any idea about hiding menu share it :) Thanks

Comment: getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
          View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);